# Zenity refuses to work in background

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal, zenity

I'm trying to create a background bash script which creates a popup in certain circumstances, however, my code only works when run manually in a terminal (e.g. not in the background). I've tried various things such as:

```
screen env DISPLAY=:0.0 su $USER -c 'zenity --warning --text "Warning message here"'
```

Or

```
screen zenity --warning --text "Warning message here"
```

I've spent hours trying various different things, and I feel like there must be a simple solution and I'm just missing something.

Nothing I've tried works while the script is run in the background with cron.

I'm running Lubuntu 12.04, LXDE.

Any ideas to why I can't get it working?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem before, when I checked `$DISPLAY`, I noticed that it had nothing, so I had to set it, and also I had to use `xhost +` to allow the message to pop-up.

Try the following command option to set the display:

```
xhost +
zenity --warning --text "Warning message here" --display="yourmachine:0.0"
```

Comment: It still doesn't work for me, unfortunately. Any other ideas?

Comment: Never mind, I've found the problem. I was running my script as root, but because I was logged in as a standard user the popup wasn't shown. (I suppose this is to stop other peoples popups appearing if there's more than one user logged in)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like OP solved it, but I had the same basic question so here's a quick solution for anyone else. When running as a background process the following error is produced:

> Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is
>   discouraged.

I am running zenity in a script via the `at -f script.sh` command, **so the environment variable `$DISPLAY` needs to be set before running the command**:

```
env DISPLAY=:0.0 zenity --warning --text "TIME TO CLOCKOUT!"
```

Now it works.